# Any exercise tips for people with spinal fusion and those who are short, but want to maintain their weight?

Tags: exercise

I am an 18 year old who's 4 ft 10 who had a spinal fusion done five years ago. I am currently 93 lbs and have been working out on my recumbent bike since the beginning of January of 2019. Due to the spinal fusion I am limited in quite a number of exercises. I can't bend or twist or carry weights higher than 8 lbs. Knowing that I'm short and that I'm not able to grow anymore, I have an easier chance of any weight gain showing. I want to take care of myself even though I'm limited. I have also been walking and running on a treadmill as well, and have been doing wall push ups because of restrictions. I try to give a half an hour every day for exercise, and I try to walk every time I can. I even noticed some muscle formation on my arms. I started worrying about my weight because I was always insecure about the way I looked, and I feel like getting fat will only make me feel more uglier and I won't feel good in my body. Do you have any exercise tips and healthy diet tips for people with my condition?